# Extract text between quotation marks google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, extract

Considering the string shown below:

```
 "text": "fkjhsabhfkjhs7g8ydfgd.",
  "e": 1541699908958,
  "test": true
```

I am trying to extract the value of the field named "text". Essentially, from within the string, I would like to capture the sub-string shown below:

`fkjhsabhfkjhs7g8ydfgd`

The length of the value of the field named "text" is not constant, it could vary.

I tried with this regex:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"""(.*?)""")
```

I did not get what I am after. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if Excel does capture groups properly, but if your input has no double quotes inside, you could try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C2, "[^""]+")
```

which matches up to the second double quote (eg. matches abc in "abc"d").

Comment: Gives me circular dependency error in Google Sheets

Comment: Oops, I made a typo in the formula. If your text is in cell XX change the first argument B2 to match XX.

Comment: I've edited the formula in the answer to reflect your current situation.

Comment: It works but it only provides true, i need the actual text within the quotes, but not include the quotes

Comment: Sorry about that, I also messed the command name. In short, you could just change the regex in your old command to "[^""]+", which is a regex that finds a contiguous string with no double quotes.

Comment: It works! Almost. Just need to only select the second field in string, in my example above that would be "text":...i just need the text after the field name. This is a JSON response

Comment: If the text field is constant, you can strip off the beginning N characters using `=RIGHT(XX, LEN(XX) - N)` , then run the regex in a different column.

Answer (score 8):

I found that if you escape the double double quotes, that it works.  The other examples don't appear to work in Google Sheets regexextract function

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"\""(.*?)\""")
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution could be

```
=regexextract(C2, "\:\s""(.+?)""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **A1** with your designated cell number and it should work

=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"""(.*?)""")